# How can i give my h1 a border at the bottom right corner with css?

Tags: css, border, html-heading

I need a corner for a h1 element in html. You can see the example on the picture. How can i do it with css?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqwS5.png "h1 Example"

Comment: @Temani Afif  What exactly is the problem of the question? It is to basic (nobeginners allowed on stakcoverflow?)? Or not specific enough? I really want to know, so i can write a better question next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple background:

```css
h1 {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue);
  background-position:bottom right;
  background-size:3px 20px,20px 3px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some text here</h1>
```

Answer (score -4):

Quite simple. You can wrap a  element into the  element and assign a border to it with `border-bottom` and `border-right`. 
Btw. this is a basic question..

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyat67vd/1/

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot. I thought there would be a more general solution than defining a span for every h1 on the page. Because all the h1 should have this border. But anyway this solution seems still easy enough.